# Why was my flooring not run through the door opening?

Tags: flooring, threshold

The flooring installed was cut not extending through the doorway (Modern LVP tongue and groove flooring). Why it was not extended through? My best guess is because of the height difference in both rooms. Due to this there there is exposed sub-flooring which isn't the end of the world but also not aesthetically pleasing. What are some remedies to this dilemma?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me how the photos relate to the question. The flooring seems incomplete in general.

Comment: "What are some remedies to this dilemma?" The remedy is to call back the people who laid the flooring and have them correctly finish the job! If not possible then @heyitsmyusername has the answer.

Comment: Is this a new floor or an old one you're trying to work with?

Comment: I appreciate all of your feedback. I will upload more pictures for better context.

Comment: Because you have to make notches in that stuff with a jig saw which is a pita. The guy who GAF wasn't there that day.

Comment: I just included another picture. The room with concrete flooring is about .5 inches lower than the vinyl room. Based off everyones answers I'll throw a strip threshold on the end of the planks. Then aluminum threshold which will end at the point where the difference in height occurs.

Comment: @Jack Old floor

Comment: Most installers will say that the "room" ends at the edge of the door and a transition piece for under the door will be extra $$$. Then the adjoining floor meets up against the transition piece. If the same flooring continues, then a transition isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

The standard arrangement is to have a threshold under the doorway, which defines and separates the rooms. I'm personally fond of the stone variant, but wood is also common, and running the flooring right under is also done, just not terribly common, especially in older work.

The threshold as a trim piece helps to ease the awkwardness of flooring changing direction as it passes under the door, or an entire hallway being oddly floored due to not changing direction at the doorway.

"Why wasn't it done?" Either the person that did it didn't want to, or wasn't paid to, or considered it an outlandish new-fangled idea they were having no part of because they didn't want to and weren't paid to. You'd have to track them down and ask them in order to know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone patched the concrete floor with the darker cement, but didn't smooth it out. You could grind it down, and smooth/fill-it with some cement made for that purpose. Once the uncovered floor is level with the flooring under the LVP, if you have extra pieces of flooring, you should be able to remove the broken piece of LVP, then attach a few pieces of LVP to complete the flooring to under the doorway.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any height difference.   Me thinks you just need to continue the flooring.    Obviously you need to flatten the concrete which is a pain.       There is nothing in the pictures showing a height offset.

Comment: Even if there is a height difference, it can be accounted for by the threshold, assuming the doorway will have one. Will it? And if not, did you discuss that with the flooring folks? (I have a threshold across a 6'-wide passageway for just this reason -- new vs old flooring not in alignment, plus a gap in the flooring where we opened the wall; all of that is buried at the cost of there being a wide, shallow bump between two rooms.)

Comment: @keshlam - yea but with the underlayment and height at bottom of door it looks about right but you can have a heightened threshold for sure that can add up to a 1/2" without disturbing anyone.